# xmlstarlet is unable to add subnode when more than one xmlns attribute is present in the first element

Tags: xml, ubuntu, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I have an xml file `test.gpx`:

```bash
cat test.gpx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <trk>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <desc>Description 1</desc>
  </trk>
  <trk>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <desc>Description 2</desc>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

[xmlstartlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is not able to perform successfully when trying to insert a subnode in this file:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit --subnode "/gpx/trk" --type  elem -n "new" -v "Hello World!" test.gpx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <trk>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <desc>Description 1</desc>
  </trk>
  <trk>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <desc>Description 2</desc>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Whereas with only one attribute in the first `gpx` element, it works:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit --subnode "/gpx/trk" --type  elem -n "new" -v "Hello World!" test.gpx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <trk>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <desc>Description 1</desc>
    <new>Hello World!</new>
  </trk>
  <trk>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <desc>Description 2</desc>
    <new>Hello World!</new>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Hence my question: how could I succeed with the original file, having more than one attribute in its first `gpx` element?

Version info:

```
xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.10, linked with 20913
compiled against libxslt 1.1.34, linked with 10134
```

On Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes your are dealing with aren't just garden variety attributes - [they are namespaces](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) and have to be taken into account accordingly. Since you have a default namespace in your first (but not second) file, you can deal with it in one of two ways.

The long, explicit way:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x=http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 --subnode "/x:gpx/x:trk" --type  elem -n "new" -v "Hello World!" test.gpx
```

or the shorter:

```
xmlstarlet ed  --subnode "/_:gpx/_:trk" --type  elem -n "new" -v "Hello World!" test.gpx
```

Either one should give you your expected output.

Comment: It seems to work, thanks, but how could I add an associated namespace into the first gpx tag. It should be `"xmlns:ogr="http://osgeo.org/gdal"`. Currently, nothing is added.

Comment: @swiss_knight - A few things: first, your question didn't mention anything about adding a new namespace declaration; as its title says, it asks about adding a subnode which is what the answer does. Second, not sure how the namespace you suggest is "associated" with the new node.